# Converting MATLAB model code to C++ and using in Linux

Tags: windows, matlab, unix

I have matlab installed in windows based system. I have generated a model for the application. 
I want to convert this code to C++ code and use it in a linux based system. I converted this code using auto coder to C code but I am not understanding how to use it in a linux based system.
Please let me know what are the steps to be followed?

Thank You

Comment: Maybe you could start with something like this: http://www.physics.drexel.edu/courses/Comp_Phys/General/C_basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a project (or a makefile for linux) around the generated C files. With a decent compiler, you should be able to compile these under Linux as well as under windows.